# Python Flask file upload and display the location

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to [upload](https://www.thamizhchelvan.com/python/simple-file-upload-python-flask/) a simple JSON file and then display the location on html page. The file upload is successful, but I am not able to display the location. I am sure there is a small mistake somewhere, but struggling to figure it out.

app.py

```
import os
import sys
import json
import glob

from flask import Flask, request, render_template, url_for, redirect

app = Flask(__name__)

filename = ""

@app.route("/")
def fileFrontPage():
    return render_template('fileform.html')

@app.route("/handleUpload", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def handleFileUpload():
    if 'json' in request.files:
        json = request.files['json']
        if json.filename != '':
            json.save(os.path.join('/PATH/', json.filename))
        filename = os.path.join('/PATH/', json.filename)
    result = 'file uploaded at' + filename
    return redirect(url_for('fileFrontPage'), result=result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

and my html page
fileform.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Simple file upload using Python Flask</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="/handleUpload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            Choose the file: <input type="file" name="photo"/><BR>
                <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
        </form>
        {{ result }}
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your endpoint for ```handleFileUpload()``` method  needs to be different than ```fileFrontPage()``` method.

Comment: Thanks !! I just realized that I should have `@app.route("/handleUpload", methods=['GET', 'POST'])`. It is still not working.